Azure Databricks: error 403 while doing dbutils.fs.ls on mounted directory
I have an Azure Databricks workspace, a storage account with hierarchical namespace enabled and a service principal. I have mounted the storage successfully (the output was "True"):
configs = {
    "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
    "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
    "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "[redacted]",
    "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "[redacted]",
    "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[redacted]/oauth2/token"
}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://[redacted]@[redacted].dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/demo",
  extra_configs = configs
)

Now I try to view the mounted directory contents:
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/demo")

and I get error:

Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this
operation using this permission.", 403, GET,
https://[redacted].dfs.core.windows.net/[redacted]?upn=false&resource=filesystem&maxResults=5000&timeout=90&recursive=false, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to
perform this operation using this permission.

I have double checked that my service principal has Storage Blob Data Contributor permissions to the storage account.
What am I doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

can you try giving inside the SA for the app azuredatabricks also storage blob contributor role and retry if you able list??

Also can you try to read any file from the storage Account?

Can you also check networking details of your underlying infrastructure such as IP addresses because the ERROR is related 403

Is this UC-enabled workspace? If so, try creating Storage Credentials & External Location.

Thanks everyone for useful tips! The problem, however, was more prosaic. It turned out that I had two Service Principals with the same name. In my code have used Client ID/Secret of first one, but I have granted Blob Contributor role to another one.

Glad you solved. But don't use mount points, they are not suggested as a solution since 3 years ago. Move to Unity Catalog and use Volumes instead

As you mentioned you have provided the SPN the Storage Blob contributor role.
I have tried mounting the ADLS and used the below it did work for me:
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/new_raw")

Results:
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/new_raw/Delta_folder/', name='Delta_folder/', size=0, modificationTime=1726556613000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/new_raw/Parquet_folder/', name='Parquet_folder/', size=0, modificationTime=1726567040000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/new_raw/control_table/', name='control_table/', size=0, modificationTime=1726556615000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/new_raw/synapse/', name='synapse/', size=0, modificationTime=1726031781000)]


When I munted the ADLS I have followed the below steps:

I have Provided My KEYVAULT Key vault adminstartor to SPN & Azuredatabricks application.
I have provided the storage blob contributor role to the
azuredatabricks application
Also please  check if the  storage has been protected by firewall. If the storage account is  storage has been protected by firewall you can add the outbound IP to the whitelist of storage.



If you are using the Unity catalog enabled workspace refer to Create a storage credential for connecting to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
